# Multi Table mapped on one class in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

we use an external Database where we cant edit table designs only add own tables to extend the core tables.

So I need map two tables on one class, i try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="DaVinci"
               namespace="DaVinci.Domain">
<class name="Vorgang" table="VORGANGSKOPF">
<id name="Id" column="ID">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="Vorgangsnummer" column="VORGANG" />
...
<join table="OWN_VORGANG_WAEHRUNG" optional="true">
      <key column="VOR_ID" property-ref="Vorgangsnummer" />
      <property name="WaehrungVK_Internet" column="WAEHRUNG" />
      <property name="WaehrungsKursVK_Internet" column="KURS" />
      <property name="Preis_Internet" column="BETRAG_EURO" />
      <property name="PreisFremdWaehrung_Internet" column="BETRAG_FREMD" />
  </join>
...
```

After testing i know now that "property-ref" for joins dosn't work. 
[Bugreport here](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1452)

Does anyone know an other way to map two tables on one class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm struggling a little with the table and column names here.)

Could you use a joined subclass for this? Even if the tables don't follow the logical relationship, if there's a 1-to-1 database relationship between the two tables, then you'd get what you want by ignoring the parent, and doing all your operations on the subclass.